# How to insert models with ManyToOne relationship using Rest framework Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

i'm learning Django rest framework and i'm looking to implement the following if it's possible, for example if it is the first time a get a parking ticket i would like to create an account for that plate number along with the Violation and if the account with the plate number exists i want to add the Violation to that account.

Result:

```
{
"id": 12,
"account_number": "0350a6ec6",
"pin_number": "54fe8e",
"plate_number": "963874",
"plate_state": "AL",
"created": "2022-01-28T16:07:26Z",
"violations": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "violation_number": "bd48668bdbf8",
    "violation_description": "bad place to park",
    "ticket_location": "ma",
    "violation_date": "2022-01-28T21:10:25Z",
    "violation_fine": "966.00",
    "violation_due": "2022-01-28T21:10:35Z"
  }
```

**my Models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db import models
from .utils import generate_account_number, generate_account_pin, 
generate_violation_number

class Account(models.Model):
account_number = models.CharField(max_length=9, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, 
editable=False)
pin_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, null=False)
plate_state = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=False, null=False)
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.account_number

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return f'/{self.account_number}/'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.account_number = generate_account_number()
    self.pin_number = generate_account_pin()
    super(Account, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


 class Violation(models.Model):
violation_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True,blank=True, null=True, 
editable=False)
violation_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
ticket_location = models.CharField(max_length=250)
violation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
violation_fine = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
violation_due = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='violations', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-violation_date',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.violation_number

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.violation_number = generate_violation_number()
    super(Violation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Account, Violation

class ViolationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Violation
    fields = (
        'id',
        'violation_number',
        'violation_description',
        'ticket_location',
        'violation_date',
        'violation_fine',
        'violation_due'
    )


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
violations = ViolationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = (
        'id',
        'account_number',
        'pin_number',
        'plate_number',
        'plate_state',
        'created',
        'violations'
    )
```

**Views.py**

```
from dataclasses import fields
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Account, Violation
from .serializers import AccountSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import AccountSerializer, ViolationSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser 
from .utils import generate_account_number, generate_account_pin
# Create your views here.
class AccountsList(APIView):
def get(self, request, format=None):
    accounts = Account.objects.all()
    serializer = AccountSerializer(accounts, many= True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass #not sure what to do here


class AccountDetail(APIView):
def get_object(self, accn):
    try:
        return Account.objects.get(account_number = accn)
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def get(self, request, accn, format=None):
    account = self.get_object(accn)
    serializer = AccountSerializer(account)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

i created some functions to generate account number, pin and violation number, im able to create accounts from django, i know i have to override some methods but im not sure which ones and if there any suggestions to improve my code that would also be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solved the problem my self, i did this in my post method:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    pn = request.data.get('plate_number')
    ps = request.data.get('plate_state')
    vd = request.data.get('violation_description')
    tl = request.data.get('ticket_location')
    vf = request.data.get('violation_fine')

    try:
        vaccount = Account.objects.filter(plate_number = pn, plate_state = ps)
      
        vserializer = vserializer = ViolationSerializer(data = {
                'violation_description': vd,
                'ticket_location': tl,
                'violation_fine': vf
            })
        aserializer = AccountSerializer(data = {
                'plate_number': pn,
                'plate_state': ps
            })

        if vaccount.exists():                
            if vserializer.is_valid():
                vserializer.save(account = vaccount.get())
                return Response({"status": "success", "data": vserializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)             
        else:
            if(aserializer.is_valid()):
                aserializer.save()
                account = Account.objects.get(plate_number = aserializer.validated_data['plate_number'], plate_state = aserializer.validated_data['plate_state'])
                if vserializer.is_valid():
                    vserializer.save(account = account)
                return Response({"status": "success", "data": aserializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"status": "error", "data": aserializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)        
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

now if the account exists it will add the violation to that account, if not it will create the account and then add the violation to that account.